# Why can't my import be resolved?

Tags: java, import

I'm trying to use this import in my program and unfortunately it is not working, I keep getting an error stating import can not be resolved. The project that I created is a "Java Project" so I'm not sure if that is causing an issue. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.abbyy.ReceiptCapture.*;

public class Hello {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        try {
            Hello application = new Hello();
            application.Run();
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            displayMessage( ex.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have that package available in the classpath? eg. via a jar

Comment: This is not a [mcve], so it would help narrow down the problem if you showed one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the standard Java naming conventions, your `import` directive looks like `ReceiptCapture` is a type, not a package. Is that correct? If so, then that import statement will not work because import-on-demand for types needs a *package* followed by the dot-wildcard sequence.

If `ReceiptCapture` is a package then its name does not follow the conventions. In that case it would help if you publish the actual error you got - what type(s) is it trying to import? Perhaps you have not set your classpath correctly.

What is your classpath?

Check out the Java naming conventions and follow them.